# Counting heavily nested XmlNodes without knowing exact structure

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to count the fields in a form that is uploaded by the user. This 'form' is coming in as an XML document. Everything is working just fine but I'm running into a problem where I need to count all of the fields in the form whereas my current code is only counting the groups and one level underneath. I need my code to go into those groups and count the fields. If those groups have groups, count those too (and keep going...). I don't even know what the number of nested groups would be because it's all up to the end user to design this form. This form could have thousands of fields, so the structure could be anything.

So, in short, I know the following XML will be provided:

```
<theFieldRoot>
   <group1>
      <field1></field1>
   </group1>
   <group2>
      <field2></field2>
      <group3>
         <field3></field3>
      </group3>
   </group2>
</theFieldRoot>
```

**Expected result would be 6**

So, my question is, I have an xml document, I want to count all the nested nodes under the root node `<theFieldRoot>`, but after this root node, I wouldn't know how it's structured. I only know there will be groups and fields. How do I count every element under `theFieldRoot` when the structure is unknown?

C#:

```
    private int FieldCount(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        int fields = 0;
        XmlNode formSchema = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Blah/Blah2");
        XmlDocument fieldXml = new XmlDocument();

        using (var sr = new StringReader("<theFieldRoot>" + formSchema.InnerText + "</theFieldRoot>"))
        using (var xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr) { Namespaces = false })
        {
            fieldXml.Load(xtr);
            XmlNode myFields = fieldXml.FirstChild;

            foreach (XmlElement xEl in myFields)
            {
                if (xEl.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    fields += 1;
                }
                fields += 1;
            }
            //if (myFields.HasChildNodes)
            //{
            //  fields = myFields.ChildNodes.Count;
            //}

        }
```

Comment: Given that sample XML, what is the expected number of `fields`, is it simply 6?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm going for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XPath `.//*` to select all elements, whatever it's name, wherever it is under current element. Then you can count them easily, for example :

```
int fields = formSchema.SelectNodes(".//*").Count;
```

Working example :

```
var xml = @"<theFieldRoot>
   <group1>
      <field1></field1>
   </group1>
   <group2>
      <field2></field2>
      <group3>
         <field3></field3>
      </group3>
   </group2>
</theFieldRoot>";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNode formSchema = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
int fields = formSchema.SelectNodes(".//*").Count;
Console.WriteLine(fields);
//output is : 6
```

**<kbd>[.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OWA3ke)</kbd>**

Comment: Wow, that simple. I knew I was overthinking something. One follow up question, ".//*" would translate to what? . = root, / = level, / = level, * = wildcard?

Comment: That can be separated into 3 parts : 1. (`.`) means current context element, which in this case is  the XML element referenced by `formSchema` variable. 2. (`//`) descendant-or-self axis, you can search that keyword for more info. 3. (`*`) as you guessed is wildcard

Answer (score 1):

Try Linq to xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
int count = xdoc.Root.Descendants().Count(); // 6
```

Descendants are the same as xpath "//*".